# Why is only one table row updated?

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

I'm trying to update the `rank` column in the `users` table in MySQL using PHP, but when I try to change the values and press the `update` button, **only the last one** of the table rows is actually being updated. Here is an image of what the PHP table looks like on the webpage:

[image: Here]

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include '../db/connect.php';
$con = $MySQLi_CON;
if (!$con){
    die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE users SET rank='$_POST[rank]' WHERE user_id='$_POST[hidden]'";
    $con->query($UpdateQuery);
}
$result = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM users") 
    or die(mysql_error());  
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
</tr>";
echo "<form action='test3.php' method='post'";
while($record = $result->fetch_array()){

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['user_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['username'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $record['email'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . '<input type="number" name="rank' . [$record['user_id']] . '" />';
    echo '<td>' . '<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="' . $record['user_id'] . '"</td>';
    echo '<td>' . '<input type="submit" name="update" value="update"' . '</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";

for($_POST['rank'] as $user_id=>$rank){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE users SET rank='$rank' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$con->query($UpdateQuery);
}
$con->close();
```

Comment: you created the form in a while loop within a table row.. so of course when you submit, only one row will be submitted.

Comment: So `echo` the `form` outside of the `while` loop and then It'll work?

Comment: It's only updating the last row because that is all you've told it to do. Look at posting arrays using forms.

Comment: yes, but you need to make adjustments with how you are posting the data.  check this ^

Comment: Your html is invalid. Using `<form>` around `<tr>` makes your browser rebuild html and you receive not what you expect. Open your generated html and see.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all rank of each row is using the same name `rank` and also the `hidden`, the browser will override all rank and hidden value with the latest element.

change `<input type="number" name="rank" />` to `<input type="number" name="rank[$record['user_id']]" />`

receive in php with `$_POST['rank']` in array format and loop each rank.

```
for($_POST['rank'] as $user_id=>$rank){
   $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE users SET rank='$rank' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
    $con->query($UpdateQuery);
}
```

Comment: it now returns this error: `syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';'` 

I updated the code above as well

Comment: first of all, I think you don't get the point. `[$record['user_id']]` will definitely be a syntax error,  the final html that you need to echo is like `<input type="number" name="rank[1]" />`. second, you didn't update the query part. third, I think you need to know how to send array data to server and how php catch array data from `POST` request.